# Dictionary of Arrays to Single Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

Simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to:

In C#, how do you take a Dictionary< TKey, TValue[] > and make it an TValue[] array - get all values from the dictionary into a single array?

I've tried experimenting with LINQ but can't find a solution, probably easier than I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) from LINQ:

```
 var array = dic.SelectMany(p => p.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I haven't used SelectMany, just Select LINQ.

Comment: if it is Dictionary, should that just be dic.Values.ToArray()?

Comment: @EthanLi: the result of your code will be TValue[][], not TValue[]